# Android - All Listeners are not working

Tags: java, android, mobile, onclicklistener

I've built an app then added some code (and pushed with git) a few times but didn't test it out. Now that I'm testing it out and it doesn't work. I would rather try to fix the problem before reverting to a past versions.

It initially seem like two buttons weren't working but no button listener works. I cannot find anything on the internet, so if you do I would appreciate it. I have zero clue whats going wrong so I have included the android manifest, and two examples where the button listener does not work.

The most recent addition to the android manifest was settings_changepassword

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.-.point">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<permission android:name="com.-.point.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.-.point.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.magnetic_field"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.-.point.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.-.point.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.-.point.Application">
    <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:1076345567071" />;

    <activity
        android:name=".launch"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".start"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.start"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.login"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".signup"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.signup"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".friends_list"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.friends_list"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".add_friend"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.add_friend"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".point"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.point"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.settings"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".settings_changepassword"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.settings_changepassword"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".notif"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.notif"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.-.point" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Example of where a button click does not work.

start.java

```
package com.-.point;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class start extends Activity {
//ImageButton loginButton;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("-----------", " Starting app");
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //here check if the gps is on.
        int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        SharedPreferences loginSharedPreferences;
        loginSharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("-",mode);
        boolean loggedIn = loginSharedPreferences.getBoolean("-",false);
        if(loggedIn == true){
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.friends_list"));
        }else {
            setContentView(R.layout.start);



            ImageButton loginButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("CLICKED","LOGIN");
                    //startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.login"));
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), login.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });

            ImageButton signup_image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
            signup_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //clickedSignUp(v);
                    Log.v("CLICK","SIGN UP WAS CLICKED");
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), signup.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });


        }



        Log.e("WORKING","LOGGING WORKS");
    }



}
```

start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout            
<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/logo_image"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_w"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:src="@drawable/login_w"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/signupButton"
    android:src="@drawable/signup_w"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:clickable="true" />
</TableRow>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found my problem in the window before. It ran a check on permissions. It loaded the start layout instead of redirecting to the starting page.

Comment: post the answer , so it might help others in future]